# 413 (Request Entity Too Large) em servidor php

Tags: ajax, file-upload, amazon-aws

estou tentando enviar um arquivo de video via ajax para o servidor porém o server me retorna 413 sempre que o arquivo é maior que uns 20 M, 
minhas configurações do apache são:

```
upload_max_filesize 5000M
memory_limit 1024M
max_input_time 6000
max_execution_time 3000
post_max_size 2000M
```

alguém ja teve esse problema? ou saberia de uma forma de fazer upload S3 sem ter que passar pelo meu servidor?

segue o código que estou usando para enviar

## teste upload

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="<?=base_url('/interation/testeRecebe')?>" multiple enctype="multipart/form-data"></input>
<button type="button" value="Upload">Upload</button>
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        add: function (e, data) {
            data.context = $('<button/>').text('Upload')
                .appendTo(document.body)
                .click(function () {
                    data.context = $('<p/>').text('Uploading...').replaceAll($(this));
                    data.submit();
                });
        },
        done: function (e, data) {
            data.context.text('Upload finished.');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Veja este link, creio que pode lhe ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3562618/2238515